# Reactjs immutable State to Mutable

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, immutable.js

We have this State:

```
import {Map, Record} from 'immutable';


export interface State {
  _id?: string;
  data: Map<string, any>;
  error: Error;
  loading: boolean;
}


export const iDSS: State = {
  _id: null,
  data: Map({}),
  error: null,
  loading: false
};


export class DatasourceState extends Record(iDSS) {

  constructor(params: State) {
    super(params);
  }

  get<T extends keyof State>(key: T): State[T] {
    return super.get(key);
  }

  set<T extends keyof State, V extends keyof State>(key: T, value: State[V]) {
    return super.set(key, value);
  }

}
```

We have requirement of setting dynamic keys in the state but getting following error because of immutability:

```
Cannot set unknown key "widget-test-2" on DatasourceState
```

`DatasourceState` has been used at multiple places in the app. Is there any easy way where we can make  `DatasourceState` mutable without changing rest of the implementation. Essentially - we are looking for a mutable `Record`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can always call `.toJS()` on any immutablejs record to get js object

https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Record/toJS

also check `toObject()`

https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Record/toObject